# In Minecraft PE server edition, why does a stone pickaxe disappear after breaking one block?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

While playing on a server running

`22:42:45 [INFO] This server is running PocketMine-MP version 1.4.1-980  (Implementing API version 1.11.00 for Minecraft: PE v0.10.5 alpha protocol version 20)`

Whenever I use my stone pickaxe or any pickaxe for that matter, it disappears after I mine a block (dirt,stone,wood) and all my other pickaxes disappear from my inventory and then randomly show up.

Anyone seen this or know what might be going on?  I am playing on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 edition.

Let me know if there is more info that I can give to help with this.

Comment: Perhaps the server owner has a plugin that could be causing this?

Comment: I am the server owner, and this is a vanilla install.